# VS Code extension development - Ask user for confirmation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my extension, when the user clicks on a link to the file that does not exist, I want to display a confirmation box. And if the user clicks on yes, I want to [create the file](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceEdit).

Is there an official way to do this? Currently, the option is only `showQuickPick()`?

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, there is also the option of `vscode.window.showInformationMessage(YOUR_MESSAGE, { modal: true }, "OK")`, which will return a `Promise` that resolves with either the string `"OK"` or `undefined`.